# Argument 'PortfolioController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-fullstack

Im new to angular and I tried to generate a project with the yeoman angular-fullstack generator. I want to add a new url /portfolio so I duplicated the main-folder on the same level and renamed it to "portfolio". 
I've created three files:

> 1) portfolio.controller.js 2) portfolio.html 3) portfolio.js

I've included the js-files in the index.html for the client like this:

```
<script src="app/portfolio/portfolio.controller.js"></script>
<script src="app/portfolio/portfolio.js"></script>
```

And the following code can be found in the controller:

```
'use strict';

(function() {

class PortfolioController {

  constructor($http, $scope, socket) {
    console.log("working");
  }
}

angular.module('myPortfolioApp')
  .controller('PortfolioController', PortfolioController);

})();
```

And this is from the portfolio.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myPortfolioApp')
  .config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('portfolio', {
        url: '/portfolio',
        templateUrl: 'app/portfolio/portfolio.html',
        controller: 'PortfolioController',
        controllerAs: 'portfolio'
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not declaring a new module, you are missing the array of dependencies:

```
angular.module('myPortfolioApp',[]) //NOTICE THE BRACKETS
  .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('portfolio', {
        url: '/portfolio',
        templateUrl: 'app/portfolio/portfolio.html',
        controller: 'PortfolioController',
        controllerAs: 'portfolio'
    }]);
  });
```

Comment: wierd, did "grunt clean" and the site worked, no error message at all. Add the brackets and it says "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider" and nothing works after that.

Comment: you can't use grunt with that code, I will edit my answer

Comment: also, better to include portfolio.controller.js after portfolio.js